# Create intersection of lines and circle using SVG and CSS

Tags: css, google-maps, svg

I am using google maps for interactive map. There is a limiatation the markers will always be a circle. I need circle along with intersection of 2 lines as shown below.

[image: Intersection of lines and circle]

I dont have access to anything except CSS. Would it be possible to add CSS so I can get intersection of lines along SVG circle.

Here is my JSfiddle code where I tried to add lines to SVG circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sreeram62/8QRAJ/

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#00FFFF" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

circle:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -125px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

circle:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -125px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: You can't use :after and :before pseudo elements for svg elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible or too hard, but I made sample code for this.
I use inline svg at filter property of circle element.
When I tested, this code worked fine at firefox only, not at chrome.
(I don't know this sample is useful for using google maps.)

see http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/39gjd/

svg:

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

css:

```
circle{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><defs><filter id='f' x='-3' y='-3' width='7' height='7' primitiveUnits='objectBoundingBox'><feFlood flood-color='black' x='-3' y='0.45' width='7' height='0.1' result='hb'/><feFlood flood-color='black' x='0.45' y='-3' width='0.1' height='7' result='vb'/><feMerge><feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'/><feMergeNode in='hb'/><feMergeNode in='vb'/></feMerge></filter></defs></svg>#f");
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats useful. But is there anything u can help me with so it works on chrome too.